# Set rootViewController inside a class of UINavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a UINavigationController in my storyboard and two viewControllers which perform the following function:

> InitialViewController: this would be the application's home screen.
>
> FirstTimeViewController: is the screen that appears when the user open
>   the app for the first time.

My UINavigationController has a class that have the following code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if ([[ReadPlist initWithPlist:@"Configuration.plist" key:@"initialConfiguration"] boolValue]){

        FirstTimeViewController *firstTimeController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"firstTimeView"]; //or the homeController
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:firstTimeController animated:NO];

    }else{

    InitialViewController *initialController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"initialView"]; //or the homeController
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:initialController animated:NO];

    }

}
```

Basically this code verify the .plist file if a particular field is active, if YES means that the application is running for the first time, in this case it calls the corresponding viewController.

But this code is not working and I see a NavigationController with a black view. All I would do is the same thing we do in the interface builder, simply drag a line from the UINavigationController inside a UIViewController and set as "Root View Controller", but in my case I'm trying to do this programmatically.

How I can do this?

Comment: In your current implementation you are pushViewController, that's the reason for back button is visible. Better set the the navigation rootViewController

Answer (score 0):

When you push to FirstTimeViewController Set Bool (User Default) in controller ViewDidload Or in your Success Code.then after set in your AppDelegate below code.

if(Bool value = Yes)

{

FirstTimeViewController *FS=[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FirstTimeViewController"]; 
        UINavigationController *navController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:FS];
        [navController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
        self.window.rootViewController=navController;
        self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}

Answer (score 0):

My answer is

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)options
{
    UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    FirstTimeViewController *firstTimeVC = [navController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@" FirstTimeViewController"];
    InitialViewController *initialVC = [navController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@" InitialViewController"];
    if ([[ReadPlist initWithPlist:@"Configuration.plist" key:@"initialConfiguration"] boolValue])
    {
       // FirstTime
       navController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:firstTimeVC];
    }
    else
    {
       // Initial
       navController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:initialVC];
    }
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```